# ASP.NET List objects merging to bind into Dropdown

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I am working on a project where I have two list objects and need to use XSLT to bind them to drop down list. How can I merge the two list object together and then convert that object to XML for the XSLT that will populate the drop down?

C# objects

```
List<CarsViewModel> CarsViewModelList = new List<CarsViewModelList>();

List<TrucksViewModel> TrucksViewModelList = new List<TrucksViewModelList>();
```

merge the two objects to make one XML file

```
XmlForm.DocumentContent = sXmlcarsTrucksViewModelList;
XmlForm.TransformSource = "/carstrucks.xslt";
```

XSLT File

```
          <select class="form-control" id="ddlDisease" name="ddlDisease">
            <option value="">Please choose a car type:</option>
            <xsl:for-each select="CottDiseaseViewModel">
              <option>
                <xsl:attribute name="value">
                  <xsl:value-of select="CarId"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:value-of select='CarName'/>
              </option>
            </xsl:for-each>
          </select>
        </div>
          <div class="form-group">

          <select class="form-control" id="ddlTrucks" name="ddlTrucks">
            <option value="">Please choose an Trucks type:</option>
            <xsl:for-each select="TrucksViewModelList">
              <option>
                <xsl:attribute name="value">
                  <xsl:value-of select="TruckId"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:value-of select='TruckName'/>
              </option>
            </xsl:for-each>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: @i-r-r What is the best way to merge the two list into an XML file that will be used for the XSLT?